# Error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state') React-Native

Tags: react-native, undefined

When I press the button "Select song,it gives me the erorr: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state')". Here is the code.

```
const Buttons = ({navigation,route,props}) => {
 
const onUploadPress = async (props) => {

  let data = new FormData();
  this.state.selectedImages.forEach((item, i) => {
    data.append("doc[]", {
      uri: item.uri,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: item.filename || `filename${i}.jpg`,
    });
  });

}


return (
  
  <View>
    {/* <Text>{this.props.route.params.params.report.value}</Text> */}
<Button title="Select song" onPress={onUploadPress} />
<Button title="Run Playlist" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Playlist',{value:param})}/>
</View>
);



};
```

Any idea what is the problem here ?

Comment: You are using functional component, there is no `this.state` or `this.props`, it's not a class. Please refer to the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `this` in functional component, you can use state like

```
const Buttons = ({navigation,route,props}) => {

const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]); // define state like
 
const onUploadPress = async (props) => {

  let data = new FormData();
  selectedImages.forEach((item, i) => { // use like this
    data.append("doc[]", {
      uri: item.uri,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: item.filename || `filename${i}.jpg`,
    });
  });

}

return (...);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use "await" somewhere in this async block ?

Comment: @TiberiuPutinaru there is no need to use `async`

Comment: Ok... but when I press the button nothing happens